# How to monitor memory metrics of Windows instances in CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to monitor the memory related metrics of windows server instance. Could someone please suggest how to enable the monitoring for windows server in CloudWatch?

Comment: it is easy for linux as aws provides the script for windows you can refer to ec2config service http://blog.krishnachaitanya.ch/2016/03/monitor-ec2-memory-usage-using-aws.html  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_WinAMI.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330555/monitoring-memory-usage-in-aws-cloudwatch-for-windows-instance

Comment: Is it Windows 2016?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cloudwatch agent - which supports windows.
See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html

It supports 64-bit versions of Windows Server 2016, Windows Server 2012, and Windows Server 2008.